# Automatically distinguish difference between multiple HDDs in linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb, external-hard-drive, usb-flash-drive

I'm running Ubuntu Server 9.10. I have two external USB HDDs.  I use them each for different backup reasons. So certain data gets stored on one HDD, and different information gets stored on the other HDD.

I want to make a script that can look at the external HDD can determine which HDD it is, so that it can copy the proper information to it. Is there a way for Linux to determine this? Like if I see one HDD as /dev/sdc1, then unplug it and plug in the other HDD, should Linux see it as /dev/sdd1 or will it be /dev/sdc1?

I'm a bit of a Linux newb and I don't quite understand how it determines the /dev/sdxx values that it assigns to drives.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Storage device identification can be performed using the `UUID` of the device. Identification based on /dev/sd* is not reliable.

In ubuntu 9.10 you can use `blkid` to list the devices' `UUID` and you can use this command in a script to properly identify a specific HDD **since `UUID` are uniquely assigned to a specific HDD**.

You can find more information [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingUUID), but note that the command `vol_id` is not available since ubuntu 9.10.

Comment: personally i'd use volume labels instead of UUIDs (i prefer human-readable to guaranteed-unique), but if `vol_id` is unavailable i'm not sure what else to use.  surely udev/DeviceKit provides some tool to do this, but i'm not finding it ATM.  if all else fails, `tune2fs -l /dev/sdXN | grep volume` would get it.

Comment: `blkid -s label /dev/sdXN` should do the job. The only problem I see with using labels is that there is no command-line program for setting labels for the different file-system types. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RenameUSBDrive#Command%20line

Comment: almost: `blkid -s LABEL /dev/sdXN` (the tags are case sensitive).  your point about setting them is wrong tho -- there are commandline programs for setting labels, it's just that each filesystem needs a different program, which can be a pain.  but i generally set labels when formatting; i rarely need to adjust them later.

Answer (score 1):

This may be considered a workaround, and not a direct answer to your question, but my approach to this problem is to create a different file on each HDD.

I have several external HDDs, so I use `touch` to create a zero-byte file like 'Music' on one, or 'Videos' on another, and then my backup script can detect what to write to it.

I *do* hope you get a definite answer to your question. I'll be interested to see it.

Answer (score 1):

Just responding to my own question for anyone else's future reference...

I've found that a good method for distinguishing between devices is to just give them labels using `e2label`.

Also, I can distinguish between devices here

```
/dev/disk/by-label/
```

and

```
/dev/disk/by-uuid
```